# How to keep from starting over on MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

My iOS8 Swift app downloads videos and saves them to disk. When a user wants to watch one of the videos, this is the code I am using:

```
let path = FileUtils.videoFolderPath().stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(videoId).mp4")
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
let myPlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(myPlayer)
```

It works fine, but this is the scenario I want to fix:

1. Start watching a video
2. Hit the home button
3. Open the app a minute or two later
4. The MPMoviePlayerViewController is gone, and if I tap the video I was watching, it starts over from the beginning.

How can I make it behave more like the Videos app on the iPhone, where the movie player stays open when I return to the app? (Also, if the movie player closes, and the user tries to watch the same video again, I want it to start where they left off)

Comment: Well, did you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` staying when going background/foreground, I don't use `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated()` but I save the instance inside my class var and I add the player with `addSubview()`.

It works very well.